# Is there any way to send email through php without access to php.ini or .htaccess files or composer?

Tags: php, .htaccess, email, ini

I'm trying to make an email form on a free hosting site, because I'm a broke college student. The free hosting site doesn't allow edits to the .htaccess or php.ini files, and doesn't have composer available. Is there any other way to configure the built-in email functions, or is there a local php library that doesn't need to be installed with composer?

For reference, I'm trying to send emails from an external account (gmail), so I will need auth abilities as well.

Comment: You could use composer locally, set up your site and then upload everything including the vendor folder..

Comment: @JimL You are correct. Thank you.